# Cannot return value from EventEmitter in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, observable

I want to call a method and get the result between the following components. I know there are better ways e.g. calling method from service directly, but I use the base component in my list component and I need to use EventEmitter to execute the method and retrieve its result. So, how can I call `getServerData` method from base component and retrieve its result via EventEmitter? When I use the following approach, it returns undefined.

BaseComponent:

```
@Output() request: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>();


list() {
    // code omitted for brevity
    const result = this.emitDataRequest(index);
    return result;
}

emitDataRequest(index) {
    return this.request.emit(index);
}
```

ListComponent:

```
request(index) {
    return this.getServerData(index);
}

getServerData(index): Observable<ListOfEmployee> {
    return this.demoService.get(index);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have a return value on an EventEmitter.
As far as I know you can do 2 things.

#### @Input callback

It is possible to pass a method to your subcomponent and use it there.

For example.

**parent component:**

```
// HTML
<app-sub [parentHook]="hook.bind(this)"></app-sub>

// TS
hook(value) {
  return value;
}
```

**subcomponent**

```
// HTML
<button (click)="getValueFromHook()">Click me!</button>

// TS
@Input() parentHook: () => number;

public getValueFromHook(): number {
  const valueFromHook = this.parentHook.call(this, 20);
  console.log(valueFromHook);
}
```

In your case you could return an Observable here.

#### @Input & @Output

You could pass the data as an `@Input` and change this when an event is emitted.
In your subcomponent you can handle the change event on the **ngOnChanges**.

For example:

**parent component:**

```
// HTML
<app-sub
  [data]="data"
  (request)="handleRequest($event)">
</app-sub>

// TS
public data = 5;

public handleRequest(request) {
  this.data = request + this.data;
}
```

**subcomponent**

```
// HTML
<button (click)="request.emit(20)">Click it!</button>

// TS
@Input() data: number;
@Output() request = new EventEmitter();

ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
  console.log(this.data);
}
```

I hope this is useful information for you.

#### @Input & @Output with Observables

Same as previous example but with observables, like this you don't have to use the onChanges lifecycle

For example:

**parent component:**

```
// HTML
<app-sub
  [data$]="data"
  (request)="handleRequest($event)">
</app-sub>

// TS
public data = new Subject();

public handleRequest(index) {
  // here you can do your request to fetch some data and fill in 
  // the data$ observable with the result
  this.fetchSomeDataBasedOnIndex(index).subscribe(result => {
    this.data.next(result)
  });
}
```

**subcomponent**

```
// HTML
<button (click)="request.emit(20)">Click it!</button>

// TS
@Input() data$: Subject;
@Output() request = new EventEmitter();

ngOnInit(): void {
  this.data$.subscribe(d => console.log(d))
}
```

Comment: **You rock!..** The first method (@Input callback) is working perfectly fine, but the second (@Input & @Output) is not working, maybe due to using `observable ` in the `handleRequest` method like `this.service.get().subscribe(data => { this.data = data; });`. Any idea regarding to the second one? Maybe I should use Promise or sync method for that.

Comment: By the way, marked as answer and voted up. Actually you deserve 5 x voted up with your useful help ;)

Comment: You can always pass an Observable as Input to your subcomponent and emit a new value after a request happens then in your subcomponent subscribe to the Input Observable and you can handle all changes there

Comment: Thanks a lt. Could you also add this as a 3rd example usage? And do you have any idea about why it does not work? I pass the data when pagination, that is why I thought the problem may be caused from observable or subscribe.

Comment: updated my answer with the 3rd example, and I believe it's indeed because you're using an observable in the OnChange. To trigger an OnChanges event the complete data should change, so to make it work you would need to create a complete new observable (which i wouldn't recommend) but if you would assign your result to an array property (and pass the array to your subComponent) then it should work, but than you lose the observable stuff in the subcomponent. It all depends on what you need for your use case

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, voted up ;) Actually, the first approach seems to be OK and enough to fix my problem. However, in the first approach, when I remove unnecessary service instance from the constructor of Base Component and getting data by calling the methid in custom component, I encounter "TypeError: Cannot read property 'getData' of undefined↵  at BaseTableComponent.hook [as parentHook]..." error. That meaning, the service in the custom method is undefined.

Comment: But I inject it to the custom component constructor that was working fine without any problem. I am wondering if I make an extra definition for the service? But I just use it in the custom component and its instance is already defined there. Any idea?

Comment: oh that's because you're using the `this` object, binding the `this` object when passing the hook should fix that (`<app-sub [parentHook]="handleRequest.bind(this)"></app-sub>`)

Comment: Do you mean the first method (@Input callback)? If so, when I use `<app-sub [parentHook]="hook.bind(this)"></app-sub>`, it seems to fix the problem :)

Comment: Do I need to add `<app-sub [parentHook]="handleRequest.bind(this)"></app-sub` to only the first approach as I said my previous comment? Like that: `<app-sub [parentHook]="hook.bind(this)"></app-sub>`. Or do I also have to add it if I try the other 2 approaches?

Comment: yes, only with the first approach

Comment: Then I updated the first approach by updating `hook.bind(this)` part so that other people would also benefit from this useful answer. I think the edit is correct?